# Wine: wdfldr.sys not found

Tags: wine

While messing around with wine and learning how to use it I tried to start a game with it (genshin impact), as expected the game doesn't work very well (it simply crash) but I found in the logs some error I would like to fix.
`00c9:err:module:import_dll Library WDFLDR.SYS (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\galyfray\\Temp\\mhyprot2.sys") not found`
After some research it seems to be a very important lib in windows and messing with it leads to BSOD but nothing about wine.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with wine 5.0.2 wich is setup to emulate like a Win10. The missing lib isn't avalable with winetricks.

I have also several others error I put them bellow if some of them are related to my problem
`wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.`

```
0030:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0030:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({5eec90ab-c022-44b2-a5dd-fd716a222a15}, 0x3161124, 0x4487e40, 0x4487e60) stub.
0030:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0x4377370, 43) stub
0035:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x46bfda0 (nil)): stub
0036:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x47cfda0 (nil)): stub
0037:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x48dfda0 (nil)): stub
0038:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x49efda0 (nil)): stub
0030:fixme:font:get_outline_text_metrics failed to read full_nameW for font L"Ani"!
0030:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
0030:fixme:toolhelp:Heap32ListFirst : stub
0030:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset TCI failing on 20000000
0030:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 20000000 file = L"/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra/aakar-medium.ttf"
0030:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x22f1f0 0x22f140 0x22f1f8) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0030:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x22efd0 0x22ef20 0x22efd8) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0030:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({d2d578d9-2936-45b6-a09f-30e32715f42d}, 0x70b8f00, 0xaf36a10, 0xb086fc8) stub.
0030:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 0x22dab0, (nil) 0x22dab8
0030:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x22dab0 (nil) 0x22dab8) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0030:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 0x22dab0, 0x5e7ec40 0x22dab8
0030:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x22dab0 0x5e7ec40 0x22dab8) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0030:fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x22d7f0 0x00000ff0 0x22d7e8) Stub!
0030:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022D520 1 C) semi-stub
0030:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022D1A0 1 C) semi-stub
0030:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022D0F0 1 C) semi-stub
0030:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x22da90, overlapped 0x5e7fa50): stub
0030:fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x101f4, filter=0x22d7e0,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
0030:fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x101f4, filter=0x22d7e0,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
0030:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset TCI failing on 20000000
0030:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 20000000 file = L"/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra/aakar-medium.ttf"
0030:fixme:font:get_outline_text_metrics failed to read full_nameW for font L"Ani"!
0030:fixme:systray:Shell_NotifyIconGetRect stub (0x22efa0) (0x22ef90)
0030:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x10204 c062 1 (nil)
0030:fixme:systray:Shell_NotifyIconGetRect stub (0x22efa0) (0x22ef90)
0044:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
0049:fixme:wlanapi:WlanEnumInterfaces (0000000000000001, 0000000000000000, 000000000E6DEDF8) semi-stub
0053:fixme:process:CreateProcessInternalW Unsupported attribute 0x20002.
0030:fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 000000000022BEA0
0055:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
0055:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({d2d578d9-2936-45b6-a09f-30e32715f42d}, 0xc28f00, 0x4aa6a10, 0x4bf6fc8) stub.
0055:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022F020 1 C) semi-stub
0055:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022ECA0 1 C) semi-stub
0055:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0044:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0043:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\C:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
0044:fixme:file:ReplaceFileW Ignoring flags 2
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\C:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
0073:fixme:time:QueryThreadCycleTime (0xfffffffffffffffe,0x9c1f060): stub!
00e9:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x570000 0 0x22da50 4 stub
00e9:fixme:heap:EnumSystemFirmwareTables (0x4649524d, 0000000000000000, 0)
00e9:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x7a0000 0 0x22f1b0 4 stub
00ea:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x9afb00 (nil)): stub
```

I hope that someone know how to fiw it I will continue my research and update if I found anything.
EDIT : I'm using WINEARCH=win64 (the game is in 64 bit as far as know it shouldn't be a problem) and a 64 bit WINEPREFIX

EDIT 2: dowloading and placing the missing file where it should be in the window file tree doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I had the same problem, it seems [WDFLDR.SYS](https://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/process.pl?p=wdfldr.sys) is a Windows's kernel driver, currently wine doen't support kernel services, but they are planning to do so, most anti-cheats uses kernel drivers, in the near future we will be able run it over wine, for now it is not possible.

Comment: I found the same error, trying to start the same game... The funny thing is that it used to work, before upgrading the game to v3.6.0... (Using Heroic Games launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the `WDFLDR.SYS` from [dll-found.com](http://www.dll-found.com/wdfldr.sys_download.html) and add it to `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/drivers`.

This would have the wine application find the DLL and use it, which may solve the issue.